# sudo can't find rospy

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are trying to run a publisher/subscriber on a raspberry pi.

The talker captures keyboard input and the listener takes the key presses and controls LEDs connected to the RasPi pins.

Everything seems to be working fine except for one annoying error.

The listener needs to be run using sudo so it can control the pins.(More info here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=22515)
But when I run the listener using sudo, I receive the error "no module named rospy". Rospy works fine when I run the listener without root.

the two commands I'm running are:
`python listener2.py`
`sudo python listener2.py`

Is there something else I should be running instead of sudo python?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221090/sudo-can%27t-find-rospy/) by [twigs](https://answers.ros.org/users/25102/twigs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-18**:
Related: [Rosrun as super user](http://answers.ros.org/question/189457/rosrun-as-super-user/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is almost certainly related to the fact that when you run `sudo python listener2.py` you are running the "python listener2.py" as a different user. When you `source` the `setup.bash` files that are either in your base install, or in a workspace, you are setting up a bunch of environment variables. One of the environment variables that you are modifying is the `PYTHONPATH` that Python uses to find modules to import. You can see this by opening a new terminal that has not "sourced" any `setup.bash` files, and run `echo $PYTHONPATH`. Then run something like `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` or `source ~/catkin_ws/setup.bash` and re-run `echo $PYTHONPATH`.

If you *must* run your node using sudo (my guess is there is a way around this... see @DanLazewatsky's answer), then you need to make sure that your environment for the root user is setup correctly. A simple way to do this would be a script that "wraps" the command you are actually trying to run. E.g. see the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
rosrun <PACKAGE> listener2.py
```

You could also work on [editing your sudoers file](http://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables) to preserve relevant environment variables (e.g. PYTHONPATH).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-18**:
Really, just don't run anything as root. In almost all cases it's just a matter of permissions, which can almost always be granted to individual users and / or groups. If you must use `sudo` (but really, don't, ever), invoking it as `sudo -H ..` is probably the easiest way.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-11-18**:
@gvdhoorn is absolutely correct... avoid requiring sudo!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is because with sudo, you're running commands in root's environment, and ROS isn't configured there. Rather than run nodes with sudo, you should [add a udev rule](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=9667) which configures the GPIO device so non-root users can access it.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2